# Combinación de selectores en CSS: combinador de descendientes y combinador general de hermanos

Tags: html, css, selectores-css

Tengo una pregunta para la para la comunidad, en diversos trabajos en visualizado la recurrente acción de unir selectores de combinación. Sé a que etiquetas afecta pero no logró comprender el por qué. ¿Cómo describirían lo que está escrito a continuación? (Se encuentra dentro del CSS dentro de un bloque de comentario). Es la unión de dos selectores de combinación: descendant selector and general siblings selector. Gracias de antemano.

```css
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #Contenedor{
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #Contenido{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px;
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
            
        }
        #Contenido > div{
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            background-color: gray;
            
        }
        /* Esta es la parte de la que hablo*/
        #Contenedor input#tab-1:checked ~ #Contenido #contenido-1,
        #Contenedor input#tab- 2:checked ~ #Contenido #contenido-2,
        #Contenedor input#tab-3:checked ~ #Contenido #contenido-3{
            opacity: 1;
        }
        /**/
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Panel</h1>
    <div id="Contenedor">
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tabs">
        <label for="tab-1">Tab1</label>
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
        <label for="tab-2">Tab2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tabs">
        <label for="tab-3">Tab3</label>
    
        <div id="Contenido">
            <div id="contenido-1">
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contenido-2">
                <p>456</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contenido-3">
                <p>789</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está haciendo el siguiente selector:

```
 #Contenedor input#tab-1:checked ~ #Contenido #contenido-1,
 #Contenedor input#tab-2:checked ~ #Contenido #contenido-2,
 #Contenedor input#tab-3:checked ~ #Contenido #contenido-3 {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Es dar opacidad 1 a los siguientes elementos:

- Al elemento `#contenido-1` que tenga un ancestro `#Contenido` que tenga un hermano anterior que sea un `<input>` seleccionado con id *tab-1* y que este tenga un ancestro `#Contenedor`.
- Al elemento `#contenido-2` que tenga un ancestro `#Contenido` que tenga un hermano anterior que sea un `<input>` seleccionado con id *tab-2* y que este tenga un ancestro `#Contenedor`.
- Al elemento `#contenido-3` que tenga un ancestro `#Contenido` que tenga un hermano anterior que sea un `<input>` seleccionado con id *tab-3* y que este tenga un ancestro `#Contenedor`.